# Writen Convolution function in matlab giving trouble

Tags: matlab, convolution

Hey there, I've been having difficulty writing the matlab equivalent of the `conv(x,y)` function. I cant figure out why this gives the incorrect output. For the arrays
`x1 = [1 2 1]` and `x2 = [3 1 1]`.

Here's what I have

```
x1 = [1 2 1];
x2 = [3 1 1];

x1len = leng(x1);
x2len = leng(x2);
len = x1len + x2len - 1;

x1 = zeros(1,len);
x2 = zeros(1,len);
buffer = zeros(1,len);
answer = zeros(1,len);

for n = 1:len
    buffer(n) = x(n);
    answer(n) = 0;

    for i = 1:len
        answer(n) = answer(n) + x(i) * buffer(i);
    end
end
```

The matlab  `conv(x1,x2)` gives `3 7 6 3 1` as the output but this is giving me `3 5 6 6 6` for answer.
Where have I gone wrong?

Also, sorry for the formatting I am on opera mini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from not having `x` defined, and having all zeroes for your variables `x1`, `x2`, `buffer`, and `answer`, I'm not certain why you have your nested loops set up like they are. I don't know why you need to reproduce the behavior of [CONV](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html) this way, but here's how I would set up a nested for-loop solution:

```
X = [1 2 1];
Y = [3 1 1];

nX = length(X);
nY = length(Y);
nOutput = nX+nY-1;

output = zeros(1,nOutput);

for indexY = 1:nY
  for indexX = 1:nX
    indexOutput = indexY+indexX-1;
    output(indexOutput) = output(indexOutput) + X(indexX)*Y(indexY);
  end
end
```

However, since this *is* MATLAB, there are vectorized alternatives to looping in this way. One such solution is the following, which uses the functions [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html), [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html), and [FLIPUD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/flipud.html):

```
output = sum(spdiags(flipud(X(:))*Y));
```

Comment: can output = sum(spdiags(flipud(X(:))*Y)); be extended for 2D convolution?

Answer (score 0):

In the code as given, all vectors are zeroed out before you start, except for `x` which is never defined. So it's hard to see exactly what you're getting at. But a couple of things to note:

- In your inner `for` loop you are using values of `buffer` which have not yet been set by your outer loop.
- The inner loop always covers the full range `1:len` rather than shifting one vector relative to the other.

You might also want to think about "vectorizing" some of this rather than nesting `for` loops -- eg, your inner loop is just calculating a dot product, for which a perfectly good Matlab function already exists.

(Of course the same can be said for `conv` -- but I guess you're reimplementing either as homework or to understand how it works?)